# Sort a table with irregular column info in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I have a messy table as per below, the data inside the table have integer and word/character.
I want to sort the table from *Info 5* to *Info 1*.

| Fruit | Info 1 | Info 2 | Info 3 | Info 4 | Info 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | q | z | 2 |  |  |
| Grape | w | 4 |  |  |  |
| Guava | e | 7 |  | u |  |
| Kiwi | r | n | s |  | m |

Wish to get the result table as below.

| Fruit | Info 1 | Info 2 | Info 3 | Info 4 | Info 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kiwi | r | n | s |  | m |
| Guava | e | 7 |  | u |  |
| Apple | q | z | 2 |  |  |
| Grape | w | 4 |  |  |  |

I have tried to use the str.contains, however it couldn't detect the integer.

```
i = ['Fruit', 'Info 1', 'Info 2', 'Info 3', 'Info 4', 'Info 5',] 

data[data[i].str.contains('', na=False)
```

Comment: What does comparing an integer to a string mean?

Comment: @FrankYellin sorry, I don't get your meaning. I try to sort the table, from A to Z, then 0-9

Comment: Usually 0-9 come _before_ A-Z, and the blank or empty string comes _before_ everything. That said, can't you just use a lambda function like `lambda x:str(x) if type(x) == int else x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to create new 5 columns with number mapping from old 5 columns. This make it easier to sort. The key function is `map`, there are other equivalent like `replace`

```
# Step 1/3: create a dictionary to convert alphabet & 0-9 to new number value only:
convert_dict = {'a':1,
                'b':2,
                'c':3} # You can start filling till z. Then for 0-9 accumulate 

# Step 2/3: iterate over 5 columns, create 5 `new {i}` columns that can be used for sort:
for i in range(1,6):
    df[f'new {i}'] = df[f'Info {i}'].map(convert_dict)

    
# Step 3/3: sort
df.sort_values(by=[f'new {i}' for i in range(1,6)], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=[f'new {i}' for i in range(1,6)], inplace=True) # remove if you no longer need
```

Comment: @AlexPhang: you're welcome. If it works, please check the tick button (below up/down vote) to accept this solution and let other people know it.